# Authorize.net error: No order id submitted

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am trying to setup Authorize.net on Magento 2.1 and got this error message when go through the checkout process.

[image]

And this is the debug information

```
[2017-06-05 05:00:27] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'x_version' => '3.1',
    'x_delim_data' => 'FALSE',
    'x_relay_response' => 'TRUE',
    'x_test_request' => 'FALSE',
    'x_login' => '****',
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_relay_url' => 'http://staggb.domain.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response',
    'x_type' => 'AUTH_CAPTURE',
    'x_fp_sequence' => '8',
    'x_invoice_num' => '000000005',
    'x_amount' => 150.530000000000001136868377216160297393798828125,
    'x_currency_code' => 'USD',
    'x_tax' => '0.00',
    'x_freight' => '10.58',
    'x_first_name' => 'Abc',
    'x_last_name' => 'Def',
    'x_company' => '',
    'x_address' => '234 140th St',
    'x_city' => 'Artesia',
    'x_state' => 'California',
    'x_zip' => '90701',
    'x_country' => '',
    'x_phone' => '0433347279',
    'x_fax' => '',
    'x_cust_id' => '',
    'x_customer_ip' => '203.219.142.34',
    'x_customer_tax_id' => '',
    'x_email' => 'support@abcd.com',
    'x_email_customer' => '1',
    'x_merchant_email' => '',
    'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'Abc',
    'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'Def',
    'x_ship_to_company' => '',
    'x_ship_to_address' => '115 170th St',
    'x_ship_to_city' => 'Artesia',
    'x_ship_to_state' => 'California',
    'x_ship_to_zip' => '90701',
    'x_ship_to_country' => '',
    'x_po_num' => '',
    'x_fp_timestamp' => 1496638827,
    'x_fp_hash' => 'a6cf6689da19d58a8367ca0bda54c42d',
  ),
) {"is_exception":false} []
```

Anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by myself by adding x_relay_url ('http://staggb.domain.com/authorizenet/directpost_payment/response) to Response/Receipt URLs in Authorize.net (Account > Settings > Transaction Format Settings > Response/Receipts URLs)